# How to create a non-blocking generator to read a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonblocking

I'm trying to create a file generator which would allow me to keep reading a file (CSV) line by line, and keep running as new lines get added to the file (like a continuous log), but also keeps waiting/running the background when no new lines are found in the logs.

I've tried using [aiofiles](https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/), but I couldn't figure out how to run the async function from my sync function/main function. Then I tried [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-io.html), and using the following code I'm able to read the lines in the file.

```
async def open_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, newline='') as f:
        first_line = True
        _reader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n')
        for row in _reader:
            if row:
                # skip header row
                if first_line:
                    first_line = False
                else:
                    print(tuple(row)) # yield tuple(row) here gives the error stated below
            else:
                await trio.sleep(1)

trio.run(open_file, 'products.csv')
```

**But the script stops after reading the rows and doesn't wait for more rows in the background**. 
And when I replace with `print(row)` with `yield tuple(row)` (which will actually return a generator), I get the error `TypeError: start_soon expected an async function but got an async generator <async_generator object open_file at 0x1050944d0>`.

So `print`ing the rows is working fine, but `yield`ing is not

How can I fix this? Also, will this be able to help read lines in parallel?
**Update**:
Please not that I've to use `csv.reader` to read the lines as some of the rows contain `\n` and this is the only way to read the record properly.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator won't help in your case because iterator stops immediately when it reaches the end of file

You could probably look up the similar functionality in the following module - https://github.com/kasun/python-tail/blob/master/tail.py

```
    def follow(filename):
        with open(filename) as file_:
            file_.seek(0,2)  # Remove it if you need to scan file from the beginning
            while True:
                curr_position = file_.tell()
                line = file_.readline()
                if not line:
                    file_.seek(curr_position)
                    yield None
                else:
                    yield line
```

Then you can create a generator that yields None if line is not ready yet and a string if there is a next line in the file available. Using `next()` function you can fetch lines one by one in a non-blocking manner.

Here is how you use it:

```
non_blocking_reader = follow("my_file.txt")

# do something
line = next(non_blocking_reader)
if line is not None:  # You need to distinguish None from empty string, so use `is not` not just `if line:`
    # do something else
# do something else
next_line = next(non_blocking_reader)
# ...
```

Comment: Will this be non-blocking? 

And if I could forego having to read a file continuously, what changes can I make in my code to actually return a generator (using yield) ?

Comment: I tried this and it's able to stay active in the background. But in my case it doesn't work (exits as soon as it's done reading the files) because I have to use the `csv.reader` as the file I'm reading has newlines within double quotes, and using the `csv.reader` has been the only working option for me to read the record properly. 

Is there any way to make it work using the csv reader? I tried this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/2005a4c194a5219cbe2736bd35aacea0) , it also has the sample data file. 

Could you please help me make it work using the csv reader?